# Uploading plain .txt to Kindle: marking bold, underline, and italics?

Tags: kindle, send-to-kindle, font-rendering

I have discovered through trial and error that plaintext (*e.g.*, `.txt`) files sent to Kindle have at least some support for markup.  I'm note sure where it happens, but if I email a plaintext file to my **Send-to-Kindle** eddress, some hints get interpreted:

- Text surrounded by `<whitespace><underscore>...<underscore>` will be rendered on the Kindle as underlined.
- Text surrounded by single asterisks (`*`) will be rendered as italic.

As an example, the following decorations in a plaintext file:

```
_this is underlined_

*this is italicised*

_*this is underlined and italicised*_
```

will be rendered on my Kindle as:

> this is underlined
>
> *this is italicised*
>
> *this is underlined and italicised*

(except I can't do the underlining here on SE, apparently.)

What I *haven't* found is any way to mark text as bold or 'heading' sizes.

Are these even supported?

Thanks!

Comment: Here on SE, bold is done with double asterisks: * * **bold text** * * Of course, no spaces between them. In the past, slashes were the delimiters for italic text, but that convention is not so common these days.

Comment: Here on SE, text becomes a headline if you "underline" it with at least one minus "-".

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm talking about `.txt` files sent to and rendered in Amazon Kindle, not here on SE. :sad:

Comment: but did you tried the double asterisk? The conventions look similar. And a triple asterisk might be bold+italic. I do not have a kindle, I cannot test it.

Comment: Yes, I believe I tried those, but I will verify again.  So far only italic has been markable.  I haven't tried including Unicode fragments (such as from https://YayText.com/ yet, either.  Thanks!